# "attempt to select less than one element" with R and json

Tags: json, r, twitter

I use the package smappR for twitter-harvesting and analysis. When using the function getTimeline (https://github.com/SMAPPNYU/smappR/blob/master/R/get-timeline.R) in this loop:

```
#import excel-file with twitter usernames    
riksdagsledamoter <- read.xlsx("lista_riksdagsledamoter_twitter.xlsx", sheetIndex=1) 

# delete MPs with out twitter account  
twitterusers <- riksdagsledamoter[!(is.na(riksdagsledamoter$twitterusername)), ] 
row.names(twitterusers) <- seq(nrow(twitterusers)) 
names(twitterusers) <- c("twitterusername", "name", "parti") #convertering to vector
twitterusersvector <- as.vector(twitterusers$twitterusername)

    for(i in 1:length(twitterusersvector)){
      user <- twitterusersvector[i]
      # user <- twitterusers$twitterusername[i]
      # rov <- as.vector(user)
      getTimeline(screen_name = user,
                  filename = "pa324.json", # where tweets will be stored
                  n=3200, ## number of tweets to download (max is 3,200)
                  oauth_folder = "~/Dropbox/Privat/R/credentials",
                  sleep=10, )
      if ( file.info("pa324.json")$size > 120000000 ){
      tweetsToMongo(file.name="pa324.json", ns="xxxx.yyyy",
                    host="192.168.x.x", username="", password="")
      file.remove("pa324.json")
      }
    }
```

I get this error:

```
Error in json.data[[tweets]] : attempt to select less than one element
```

I have googled it and have tried:

```
row.names(twitterusers) <- seq(nrow(twitterusers))
```

With no help. What could be wrong?

Comment: Try to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The reason is that in this line of `getTraceback`: `max_id <- json.data[[tweets]]$id_str`, `tweets` is equal to 0 because `json.data` is an empty list. (Try `list()[[0]]` and you'll get the same error). This means the function downloaded 0 tweets. It is impossible to tell why without knowing the details of your query, which are not posted here.